# Opencart - cant change js files. adding kind of reddots at the end

Tags: javascript, opencart, opencart-3, opencart2.3

firstly very sorry, I cant find out what the real problem is.
I ll try to explain.

My client given code which is developed using `opencart` and `nitropack`.

he includes `common.js` in header, it is basic js file with some ajax calls, UI events etc which has 1297 lines(no formating in code, lots of blank spaces, blank lines etc).

my real problem is, when I made any changes in this file,

the browser console is throwing error `invalid or unexpected token`.

I checked the `common.js` file in browser console, seeing that some kind of reddots added at last of the file. I just added a `alert()` at the begining of file. nothing else.

[image: Red dots added at last of the line]

very sorry, dont know how to explain more detaily. 
This is the first time I have seen this kind of issue.

when I removed the alert(), the error gone.

Comment: try saving this js file without BOM. this could be the issue. let me know if that helped.

Comment: Check Your editor. Did You edited file in `UTF-8` mode? Or converted it to/from? The file must have correct encoding. And check @DmitriyZhuk comment too.

Comment: @ArnisJuraga - Yes, my editor is showing UTF-8 and Iam using phpStorm. what is the correct format to solve this? what if I use notepad++ for editing? is this a problem of editor?

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran One mor thing - check OC settings for "compression" under Server settings. Switch it off. Another - try to narrow down the problem. Crate empty .html file, with the same source code. Crate empty OC .tpl file  with only this code and so on.